# Tool for resizing images to square with white background

Tags: image, background, resize

Now I have a lots of pictures. they comes in many dimensions,aspect ratios. for example. **100px*500px,600px*200px,1000px*700px**.

Now I want a tool for me to resize all the images to square shape , but never distort or stretch the image , **padding white background instead**.

the result I want , **500*500 , 600*600, 1000*1000**, but have white background.

I find irfanview can not make it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageMagick thumbnailing capabilities with `-extent` and `-background white` options: see this [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad).